# Battery drained extremly fast and too much heat: Asus FX506

Tags: battery, asus

I have recently bought an Asus TUF F15 laptop (FX506HF) with these specifications:

- 12 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-11400H @ 2.70GHz
- 8 gigabytes of ram
- Nvidia RTX 2050 (4 GB)

First, I installed fedora 39 with instructions given by [asus-linux](http://asus-linux.org) site's guide. I have switched to integrated GPU. The problem I have with this device is that it drains battery in a unreasonable way. Battery would not last even 1 hour in normal mode. Another problem is that it gets way too hot (50 C at least when idle). Fans do not work in normal mode and power save mode. Fans just work in performance mode in a regular speed (not even full speed).

So:

- Is there any way to find out what process or software consumes this much battery?
- How can I configure my fans to start working in normal mode or whenever I reach 40 degrees for example?

Comment: You asked this yesterday, did you not? And you've now deleted that post?

Comment: Yeah. That post was really vague.